# Директория расширений и php.ini при сборке PHP 5.6.8

Tags: php, linux

Скачал и собрал с гита php, указав для конфигуры ключ --prefix=/usr. Во-первых php.ini отсутсвует в /usr/lib, но и без него нормально работает. Но самое непонятное, это когда при выполнении скрипта я задаю расширение -dextension=myext.so, а мне выдает ошибку, что файл отсутствует в папке /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/, откуда взялась папка local непонятно. Конечно, я могу задать параметр extension_dir или вовсе загружать модуль с полным путем, но меня интересует так и должно быть, или это какой-то глюк - отсутствует php.ini и каталог расширений по-умолчанию непонятно откуда берется? Возможно, необходимы доп. ключи для конфигуры?

Comment: по поводу используемых путей к различным компонентам и прочей полезной информации можно обратиться к самому php, выполнив команду `php -i`. у неё должен быть довольно длинный вывод, который удобнее просматривать с помощью какого-нибудь `pager`-а : `php -i | pager`

Comment: да, забыл добавить, что php -i и показывает адрес с /local, что логично, но команда php-config --extension-dir показывает уже верный путь, что уже совсем выбивается из логики

Comment: у вас несколько php собрано и установлено?

Comment: @toly нет, один

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В итоге разобрался. По поводу двоякости путей причиной была предыдущая запущенная конфигура без ключа --prefix, перед повторным запуском нужно запустить `make distclean`. Что касается php.ini, то судя по всему он и не должен автоматом копироваться командой `make install`, а копируется вручную из корня дистрибутива php.ini-production или -development.